# Creating a windowed menu in ruby ncurses

Tags: ruby, ncurses, curses

I'm trying to learn ruby and ncurses a bit more by creating a small menu in ncurses which lists different interfaces and the interface configuration for the selected interface.

Since the [ncurses library](https://github.com/sup-heliotrope/ncursesw-ruby) I want to learn does not really have a documentation and no menu examples, I tries learning from the [NCurses Programming HowTo](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/menus.html).

The code I have atm produces the following screen when started up (foo is selected but missing), the cursor is here at 2/2 (x/y) in the subwindow:

```
 ┌────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │                                        │
 │ >                                      │
 │                                        │
 │   bar                                  │
 │                                        │
 └────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

And when selecting the other one (bar is selected but replaced with the marker), the cursor is here at 2/2 (x/y) in the subwindow:

```
 ┌────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │                                        │
 │   foo                                  │
 │                                        │
 │ >   >                                  │
 │                                        │
 └────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

The question now is: where is the error or is it a problem with the library?

Thank you in advance.

### Code

```rb
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'ncurses'

$number_of_mgmt_devices = 2

# start ncurses
stdscr = Ncurses.initscr
Ncurses.cbreak
Ncurses.noecho
stdscr.keypad(true)

$foobar = Hash(:foo => "AAAAA", :bar => "BBBBB")

# create window and grab keyboard control
length = $number_of_mgmt_devices * 2 + 1
width = 40
devicesMenuWin = Ncurses.newwin(length+2, width + 2, 6, 1)
devicesMenuWin.keypad(true)

# create choices
choices = []
$foobar.each do |key, info| 
    choices.append(Ncurses::Menu::ITEM.new("#{key}", "#{info}"))
end

# create and configure menu
devicesMenu = Ncurses::Menu::MENU.new(choices)
devicesMenu.opts_off(Ncurses::Menu::O_SHOWDESC)
devicesMenu.opts_off(Ncurses::Menu::O_NONCYCLIC)

#associate windows with menu
devicesMenu.win = devicesMenuWin
devicesMenu.sub = devicesMenuWin.derwin(length, width, 2, 2)

devicesMenu.set_spacing(0, 2, 0)

devicesMenu.mark = " > "

Ncurses.box(devicesMenuWin, 0, 0)
devicesMenu.post
devicesMenuWin.refresh

begin
    while c = devicesMenuWin.wgetch; c != "o"
        case c
        when Ncurses::KEY_UP
            devicesMenu.driver(Ncurses::Menu::REQ_PREV_ITEM)
        when Ncurses::KEY_DOWN
            devicesMenu.driver(Ncurses::Menu::REQ_NEXT_ITEM)
        end
        devicesMenuWin.wrefresh
    end
ensure
    devicesMenu.unpost
    Ncurses.echo
    Ncurses.nocbreak
    Ncurses.nl
    Ncurses.endwin
end
```

Comment: You most likely aren't moving the cursor properly before sending text to the screen.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs but shouldn't the menu driver do that for me?

Comment: "Should" isn't really the point. I don't use ncurses enough to say; all I can tell you is that your output is clearly in the wrong place, which means the cursor isn't where you think it is. Why not put in Window#curx and Window#cury to find out where your cursor really is, and then try to debug from there?

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs Thank you for that tip.
I figured from the c documentation/example that the menu driver should be responsible for that since the cursor does not get moved manually.
I've tested your theory and sadly the cursor is for that subwindow at 2, 2 and 2, 4 (x, y) which makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out a few different things the problem is the underlying library used for that or better the linking.

I've tested two different systems:

- debian with ruby-ncurses 1.4.9-1+b6 (includes wide char support) -> problematic behaviour
- fedora (38) with rubygem-ncursesw 1.4.10-10 which just works

While some libraries like the fedora one link correctly against the menuw library (the one with widespace-char support), the debian one only links against the widespace-char supporting libraries panelw, formw and ncursesw but not the menuw, which is the error.

Thank you all anyway. I'll add more information when I'll find more.

Answer (score 1):

Why go through all the trouble of ncurses for a text based menu ?
Installation is cumbersome, couldn't install in on Windows to reproduce your problem.
Nowadays you have a Ruby GUI libary that has no dependencies.
https://rubygems.org/gems/glimmer-dsl-libui/versions/0.7.8
Here an example

```
require 'glimmer-dsl-libui'
include Glimmer

menu('Actions') {
  menu_item('Choice 1') {on_clicked {msg_box "Choice 1"}}
  menu_item('Choice 2') {on_clicked {msg_box "Choice 2"}}
  quit_menu_item
}

window {
  title 'Menu testing'
  content_size 300, 200
  on_closing {puts 'Bye Bye'}
}.show
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a very fair point and I wish I could easily switch but sadly I'm more or less forced to use ncurses.